# Python - Complete difference between two lists same length

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a = ['Peter', '1982', '2000', 'Homeland', '10.34']
b = ['Peter', '1982', '2000', 'Homelnad', '10.32']
```

and I want comlete diff.
So I want output like this:
['', '', '', '', '10.32']
So I want just changed values at right place.

Is there some built in function for this? What is fastest way of doing this? Do I have to do it "manually" like this?

```
i = 0
new_list = []
for item in a:
    if item != b[i]:
        new_row.append(item)
    else:
        new_row.append('')
    i += 1
    new_list.append(new_row)
```

Comment: Your example is wrong, `'Homeland'` and `'Homelnad'` are different. Also you missed the definition for `new_row` in your code

Comment: What if `b` has a change to a blank string?

Comment: Yes, I made an error in word "Homelnad", so ignore that please. There can't be blank value in my project, therefore I can use it as "unchanged value".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a builtin, but here's a shorter "manual" way:

```
In [1]: a = ['Peter', '1982', '2000', 'Homeland', '10.34']

In [2]: b = ['Peter', '1982', '2000', 'Homelnad', '10.32']

In [3]: [be if ae != be else '' for ae, be in zip(a, b)]
Out[3]: ['', '', '', 'Homelnad', '10.32']
```

Comment: how about `izip` from `itertools`

Comment: @vivek That could save some memory, but the code won't work on Python 3. In Py3 `zip` behaves like `itertools.izip` from Py2.x.